# Emit data from stencil component to ReactJs component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stenciljs

How to catch emitted data in stencilJs component in ReactJs component?

I've created a `CustomInputStencil` component that has a prop of `onChange` that accepts a function. Inside the component I call the prop like this:

```
this.onChange(newData)
```

I'm expecting that whatever function I pass on the prop, it will receive the `newData` as a value. But it is not working:

```
<CustomInputFromStencil  onChange={(typedString) => console.log(typedString }/>
```

I want to get the value of the `'typedString'` inside the stencil component but I am failing to do so.

Any tips/links that you can share?

I've been following this link:

https://stenciljs.com/docs/events

But I'm not sure how can I catch the emitted data/event in ReactJs without the use of @Listen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you wouldn't pass a function as a prop to the stencil component, as HTML would only accept attributes as string, so your function might being translated as a string property, the same happen when we're passing object as prop to a stencil web-component.

Try the following approach using [Stencil Events](https://stenciljs.com/docs/events) and see if it works

```
import { Component, Element, Event, EventEmitter, h } from '@stencil/core';

.
.
.
export class CustomInputStencil {

    @Event() changeInput: EventEmitter<string>


    render() {
        return (
            <Host>
                <input type="text" onInput={(event) => this.changeInput.emit(event.target.value)} />
            </Host>
        )
    }
}
```

And then listen to the `changeInput` event as the following

```
<CustomInputStencil onChangeInput={({ detail }) => console.log('detail', detail)} />
```

**Note*: When you're creating [Custom Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) you name them to whatever you like, just ensure you're not naming as DOM native events (such as `change`, `input`, `click`, so on...)

**Note 2*: As you saw, I've used the event in the `React` side as onChangeInput, that's how Stencil will translate your event name, with the prefix `on` followed by your event name in camel case.

*Also*, take a look into the following Stencil doc: [Listening to events from a non-JSX element](https://stenciljs.com/docs/events#listening-to-events-from-a-non-jsx-element) and in this great medium article [Using Objects/Arrays as Props in Stencil Components](https://gilfink.medium.com/using-complex-objects-arrays-as-props-in-stencil-components-f2d54b093e85)